# How do I update a column based on other columns in the same row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a table called User.
It has three columns called `Score1`, `Score2` and `Score3`.

`Score1` and `Score2` rely on the user inputting data but I want `Score3` to be the sum of `Score1` and `Score2`. How do I implement this? Is the logic for this rendered in the model. If so what does it look like? Or is it something that gets set up in during a migration when specifying the database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to set a method like this to get the sum of `score2` and `score3` attributes:

```
def score3
  score1 + score2
end
```

Comment: So you can't specify in SQLite that a column automatically updates based on other columns?

Comment: @SebastianZeki: You can write a trigger on update or insert, but this approach seems to be neater – it doesn't store extra data for the easily calculated index.